# Snowflake stored procedure parameter problem

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to log an error that happens in stored procedure:

```
catch (ERROR)  {
      snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_update_log_command, binds: [RUN_ID, PROCESS_ID,'error', 0, ERROR.message] });
        return "Failed: " + ERROR.message;
    }
```

sql_update_log_command executes procedure "update_process_log" and binds those 5 arguments. But, when error happens columns that should contain error message stays empty.
Error was something like this:

"Failed: Numeric value '$METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER' is not recognized
File 'data/stage/20220104/user_activity/20220104-172435475.csv.gz', line 2, character 1
Row 1, column $METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER
If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client."

Procedure "update_process_log" signature:

```
create or replace procedure metadata.update_process_log(
    RUN_ID FLOAT, 
    PROCESS_ID FLOAT, 
    PROCESS_STATUS VARCHAR,
    NUM_OF_RECORDS FLOAT,
    ERROR_MSG VARCHAR)
returns string
  language javascript
```

Does it look like dollar sign $ is making a problem? How can this be handled?

Comment: What will happen if you use: `snowflake.execute({sqlText: 'call metadata.update_process_log(:1, :2, :3, :4, :5)', binds: [RUN_ID, PROCESS_ID,'error', 0, ERROR.message] });`

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution in this question - [Snowflake working with stored procedure on error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64500277/snowflake-working-with-stored-procedure-on-error-handling)

Basically you have to escape single quotes before logging rows:

```
err.message.replace( /'/g , "''" )
```